# How to setImageBitmap from drawable? [Kotlin]

Tags: image, android-studio, kotlin

I want to setImageBitmap from drawable, but I couldn't do it. Can someone help me, please?

```
secretimg!!.setImageBitmap(drawble/lock.png)
```

its from the kotlin class, not from kotlin.xml

Comment: Why you are converting drawable to bitmap and setting to imageView when you can directly set a drawable to ImageView using imageView.setImageResource()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
 val icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources,
                R.drawable.lock)

secretimg!!.setImageBitmap(icon)
```